# Sharing data between all map tasks located on same machine

Tags: java, mapreduce, share

All map tasks running on the same machine, can benefit shared memory but how?
more specific, I want to share a hash-table between all same-machine located map task. my question is what is the best way to do it? I try java RMI but its performance is not acceptable for me.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks, a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `hadoop`,you may configure a map node and a reduce node on a single machine.

As you described above, you want **share** a hash table.As far as I know you may need convert this hash table to a `hadoop` recognized format, then write the map and reduce task,finally doing some single node running configurations,`hadoop` will do the work.

Not a `hadoop` expert here,just my understandings.

A side point,you could just use Thread to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to share data between map and reduce tasks. I just want to share hash table between map tasks residing on the same machine. Moreover, I cant use thread because map task are executed on different jvms, as I know.